# Create a method attribute in a class

Tags: python

I can create a function of the following format.

```
def bar():
    if not hasattr(bar, 'c'):
        bar.c = 0
    bar.c += 1
    return bar.c
```

When run it produces the following output, as intended:

```
>>> bar()
1
>>> bar()
2
>>> bar()
3
```

But if I suddenly move this function to a class, Python gives me an error.

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        if not hasattr(self.bar, 'c'):
            self.bar.c = 0
        self.bar.c += 1
        return self.bar.c
```

Now I get

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar()
...
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'c'
```

It's telling me it has no attribute, but I'm trying to create the attribute. What's going on here?

Comment: You aren't allowed to create new attributes of instance methods.  Use an instance attribute instead.

Comment: @zondo Is there a reason for this? I find this both odd and unexpected behavior.

Comment: Probably because there isn't really a good reason to use them.  If you have an instance method, that means you have an instance.  It is much better to use an instance attribute than an instance method attribute.

Comment: @JGreenwell: The difference here is between instance attributes and method attributes, not instance attributes and class attributes.  Am I reading those wrong?

Comment: @JGreenwell I'm not seeing how class vs instance attributes is related to my question. @zondo I can accept that that's just how things work, but it makes more sense to me to keep `c` as a part of the `bar` method as `c` relates primarily to `bar` (being a counter for it) and it seems unnecessary to carry around that instance with the class itself.

Comment: @zondo yep, sorry. Just really tired eyes on my part.

Comment: I think the problem is that `bar` is bound to an instance in the context shown, so Python won't allow attributes to be set in it.  In Python 3, you can refer to `Foo.bar` which, again in Python 3, is a function, and you *can* set its attributes since it is unbound.  This doesn't work in Python 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the python documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=instancemethod) "However, since method attributes are actually stored on the underlying function object (meth.im_func), setting method attributes on either bound or unbound methods is disallowed."

In other words, we could have tried `Foo.bar.im_func.c = 0`, but unfortunately, it is read-only, so it doesn't work.

Therefore, for what you try to accomplish,  I would suggest

```
class Foo(object):
  c = 0
  def bar(self):
    Foo.c += 1
    return Foo.c

f = Foo()
print f.bar()
print f.bar()
print f.bar()
```

Works on python2 and python3.

The only "drawback" is that `c` would be available to any other method of class `Foo`.

Comment: This corroborates what zondo said above. Just something I'll have to accept I suppose.